# Any way to do Android binding with Lombok accessors?

Tags: android-layout, lombok, android-binding-adapter

I'm starting to play with Android binding.  The standard (1-way) binding is to the point of being good enough for the people I hang out with.

However, I find that I can't use Lombok accessors without a `Could not find accessor` error.  Have you found a way around this, shy of manually writing getters and setters like some kind of Lombok-ignorant cavebeast?

```
@Bindable
@Getter @Setter
private String stringField;

//Must uncomment hand-coded accessors to compile!
//public String getStringField() { return stringField;}
//public void setStringField(String s) { stringField = s;}
```

For posterity, my original sample code was using a boolean, which clouds the issue a little:

```
    @Bindable 
    @Getter @Setter private boolean showpassword = false;

/*  This only compiles if the handcoded accessors are uncommented.

    public boolean getShowpassword() {
        return showpassword;
    }
    public void setShowpassword(boolean b) {
        showpassword = b;
    }
*/
```

Answer (score 3):

For `boolean`, by default the generated "getter" is `isShowpassword`, following the beanspec. The generated "setter" is `setShowPassword`. The error message suggests it is the "getter" that cannot be found.

You can use a configuration key to change this behavior. According to the [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html), if you include the following in [`lombok.config`](https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration.html) your program should work without the hand written getter and setter:

```
lombok.getter.noIsPrefix = true
```

Comment: I've used a bad example; it's the same error when bound to a lombok-accessed String.  But yes, same error when noIsPrefix is set.  And the errors go away with no changes other than adding hand-coded accessors.

Comment: Is this related to [Android studio 2.1.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37426036/android-studio-not-playing-well-with-lombok) ?

Comment: That's what I'm using, I haven't tried to build with anything else.  Does it work for you with some other development environment?