# Android Studio not playing well with Lombok

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, lombok

I just upgraded to the latest Android Studio (2.1.1) and now it’s acting strange concerning Lombok. I have an arrangement such that class Dog implements interface IDog.

```
@Data
class Dog implements IDog{
  private final List<String> toys;
}

interface IDog{
  public List<String> getToys();
}
```

Before the upgrade to `2.1.1` I never had a complaint, but now here is what’s happening

1. In the IDE everything looks normal: no red squiggly underline asking Dog to implement getToys.
2. When I run the code, Gradle complains that the Dog should implement getToys.
3. So to check if Lombok is just not there, I comment out `@Data`. As soon as I do the squiggly underline comes.

So it’s as if Android Studio understands that Lombok is handling the getter creation but Gradle does not see it. Has anyone found a solution to this?

Comment: You should've provided error log here.